# How to create permalink with php in nginx server?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm trying to create a friendly url using php in nginx server, but i got "File not found."

My example url is: http//localhost/post/123/title

and my nginx conf is:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /post {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/post/(.*)$/(.*)$ /post/postsingle.php?id=$1&title=$2;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

I got File not found.

Comment: You have an embedded `$` within your regular expression.

Comment: `rewrite ^/post/(.*)/(.*)$ /post/single.php?id=$1&title=$2;` is it right?